# Transmitting primitive data such as an int,float-tuple: More efficient to parse strings or convert to byte array?

Tags: java, mapreduce, bigdata, byte

When doing a lot of MapReduce operations, I'd like the data that is transmitted to have as little overhead as possible. One of the things I currently need to transmit a lot of are (int,float) tuples, amongst others. I am currently trying to choose between two means of transmission:

1. Serialize to string, e.g. "4,3.4". If I use ASCII-US I'm guessing the size of the transmitted object would therefore simply be the amount of characters needed in stringform, ie if my integer number is long or my float is precise, the object might get quite big.
2. Serialize to byte array: Use 4 bytes for the int, 4 bytes for the float. That way I would always be using 8 bytes. I could be using less with the string in special cases, but am guessing that the string way will be more expensive on average.

I'm therefore currently leaning towards the second option, although converting is slightly bit more complicated than just serializing to string, it should be more efficient, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather complicated question.

- On the one hand, it is (relatively) computationally expensive to convert a number from binary to text form ... and back.  Converting to decimal is particularly expensive because the conversions involve repeated division / multiplication by 10.
- On the other hand, if the data values are (on average) small, a textual representation may (on average) occupy fewer bytes when encoded.   Depending on end-to-end speed and latency of your networks (including NICs, virtualization, etc) a smaller on-the-wire representation may result in greater throughput.
- On the third hand, this would be moot if the communication costs were an insignificant part of the overall computation.

My advice would be:

1. Beware of premature optimization!
2. Benchmark the two alternatives (binary and text) for encoding + transmission + decoding *in your environment*.  Make sure that you do this with test data that will be typical of your actual data.
3. Benchmark the application as a whole.  (This assumes that you paid attention to the first point!)
4. Decide if the differences in binary versus text representation would make a *significant* difference to *overall* performance of the complete application on real data.
5. Rework the code ... if your measurements, etc tell you it will be worth the effort.

Note: if measurement tells you that the difference between binary versus text is actually significant for your application, that *could* be a sign that your computation is spending too much time doing communication versus computation.  It would be worth looking to see if you could reduce the *amount* of communication; e.g. by changing the granularity of the computation, or the amount of data that is being moved around.

---

Finally ...

> When doing a lot of MapReduce operations, I'd like the data that is transmitted to have as little overhead as possible.

This should not be your goal.  The goal should really be:

- Make the application *as a whole* go fast enough to meet performance requirements.
- Optimize *developer time* by not trying to achieve performance *in excess* of the actual requirements.

Goals like "as fast as possible" or "as efficiently as possible" or "as small as possible" can be dangerous effort sinks.  You should try to avoid them.

Comment: True, I tend to forget that premature optimization is the root of all evil, haha. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data into byte by convert using the ASCII or UTF-8 format.

Simply convert the string to a byte array and pass the format as ASCII/UTF-8
I would recommend UTF-8 because it will support more special characters than ASCII.

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

By deserialising you can easily convert the byte array to a string.